# I have to keep logging back in on the Minecraft launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

This isn't a big problem, but... On the Minecraft launcher, about 20% of the time when I open it (And I open it atleast 5 times a day, so this happens often) it will have logged me out and I have to put my password in again. After I do it works, but I was just wondering whether this was a problem. I don't think this is meant to happen as it only started recently. What is this?

Comment: Is your internet connection slow or unstable? Sometimes that happens when you don't have internet while you start the launcher. Just a few seconds without internet in the wrong moment can be enough for that.

Comment: My connection should be alright.... will do a speed test.

Comment: Can't answer yet, so here for anyone willing to write it into an answer: For Linux installations - Minecraft has provided this Link: https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4408668374925-Secure-Token-Storage-Failure-on-Linux that informs users how to connect a Snap (Ubuntu Software Center) installation to the password manager that is needed to store the login. I couldn't figure out how to actually apply it yet.

Comment: and with the platform change that recently happened this is even worse now, microsoft has made all our nightmares come true, that 20% has jumped up to like 80%

Answer (score 1):

If the remember me option isn't working, try and change your password. If someone else is using your account, it'll invalidate your session, forcing you to log in again.

Comment: I will change my password and get back soon whether it changed.

Answer (score 0):

On the log in page, make sure you click on the box at the bottom that says "Remember me" until the box turns green. Then log in, and it should remember your account the next time you open the launcher.

Comment: I'm nearly positive I've always got "remember me" ticked. I'll check

Comment: Yep, remember me is ticked.